# How to use Java CAPS SWIFT Message library

Tags: java, jcaps

I'm interested in the message library for SWIFT for Java CAPS. Is there any way to use it as an API in an existing java application ?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21454_01/html/821-2582/toc.html

Appreciate any advise on this.